# Find a string in a sentence starting with # symbol in java

Tags: java

I am looking for a piece of code in java using which I can get string starting with a # symbol in a sentence or paragraph. This is what I have tried but it didn't work for me.

```
String str = "You can use a Matcher to find all matches to a regular repression #myString";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(#)\\w*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) { 
    String match = m.group();
    System.out.println(match);
}   
System.out.println("Matches: " + m.matches());
```

Comment: `String s = "#abc";` gets a string starting with #, or can you be more specific?

Comment: Vote for Close since OP's lack of contribution to solve the issue.

Comment: Forgot to complete your question? then edit your question. Else question will close soon.

Comment: Don't want to do your home work. Else you provide what you have tried

Comment: I have tried Matcher...but I don't know the regex which I can use...I googled the solution once and Matcher thing worked but I lost that piece of code...

Comment: wan't all words starting with # in a sentence?

Comment: @ShanAli you don't need `Regex` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `regex` here. You can try with [String#startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String str = "You can use a Matcher to find all matches to a regular repression #myString";
String[] arr=str.split(" ");
for(String i:arr){
     if(i.startsWith("#")){
          System.out.println(i);
      }
 }
```

Comment: "You don't need `regex`", yet you use one.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire yes `" "` :)

Comment: But if a paragraph contains 10000 words don't you think that your code will consume more memory or it will run a loop up to 10000 to get string starting with #...?

Answer (score 0):

Upto Java 6 substring was an O(1) call but it has changed to O(n) from java 7. So, split will take extra array space which you might not need and also make copies of every word (Since Java 7).  You can just scan your string from left to right and keep looking for words starting with #, this will only make copies of words that actually starts from # and only scan the string once.

```
    String str = "asldfnlsd #dlfsnl sdlfn #ldnf dsf";
    int start = -1;
    int end = 0;
    while (true) {
        start = str.indexOf("#", start + 1);
        end = str.indexOf(" ", start);
        if (start > 0) {
            if (end > 0) {
                System.out.println(str.substring(start, end));
            } else {
                System.out.println(str.substring(start));
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution take a look at this do you think that this one is more efficient?

```
String yourString = "hi #how are # you";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)").matcher(yourString);
        while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

        }
```

Comment: This will do same thing internally :). But it will also split the word having # in it. Like "abc #ef#gh ij", will give ef and gh instead of #ef#gh.